# How to reference 'nested' #WORKSPACE_FILES# - APEX 21.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working on overriding the default style of the login page for some of our applications. I have it working as expected if I put the following CSS into the `CSS Inline` section of the `Login Page`:

```css
/* Override Oracle's Universal Theme CSS Variables */
:root {
  --ut-body-text-color: rgb(249, 249, 249, .7);
  --ut-login-region-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .4);
  --ut-login-logo-size: 200px;
}

/* Customize Login Logo */
span.t-Login-logo {
    background-image: url(#WORKSPACE_FILES#imgs/login-logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Customize Login Background */
body.t-PageBody--login {
  background-image: url(#WORKSPACE_FILES#imgs/login-background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

When I move this code into a css file & upload it into the `Workspace Files Shared Objects`, and use the given reference url in the `CSS File Urls` section - the CSS doesn't work as expected anymore. I'm guessing this is caused by the fact that APEX does not expand substitution strings inside static files (e.g. my calls to background-image urls).

Is there a way to use "nested" #WORKSPACE_FILES# calls in static files?

***Ignore the non-matching image file names below...that was me not doing a good job with screenshots assume there is a login-logo.png and login-background.jpg file and they are referenced correctly in CSS***

[image]

Comment: Ideally, you would map your custom content to a location other than the one mapped to /i/, such as /c/, so APEX upgrades would not impact your custom content.

Comment: I'm sorry Scott, unfortunately, i'm not really following your above comment. Could you explain in a little more detail "map to location other than the one mapped" and "/i/" and "/c/"? Apologize and appreciate your patience

Comment: There's limited examples out there so far, but here is one blog covering the topic http://apexdontpanic.blogspot.com/2019/04/static-files-outside-apex-images-folder_19.html  The exact solution will depend on your application server. #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# translates to /i/, while your own &APEX_CUSTOM_PATH. might map to /c/ as the relative path.

Comment: Thx I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store a CSS file as a Static Workspace or Application File, you can use relative URL references within your CSS file to reference other files. Change your CSS to:

```
span.t-Login-logo {
    background-image: url(imgs/login-logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

to read **imgs/login-logo.png** from the "imgs" directory of Workspace Static Files.

Comment: Morning Patrick, this worked, but I had to make a small tweak to relative URL in the above code. With the above, APEX was resolving the url to ''...files/static/v56/css/imgs/login-logo.png' instead of '...files/static/v56/imgs/login-logo.png'. So modified to use "url(../imgs/login-logo.png' and this worked. Thank you very much for your help!